# Jersey Rx and parallel REST request

Tags: java, jersey, rx-java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm looking to use the jersey rx client.

My requirement is to

(1) To be able to call a dynamic number of POST requests based on some database values all with different URLS.  Typically it will be less than 10 requests (same Base URLS different end point based on whats in my database).

(2) Be able to aggregate all the results from all the requests in (1) so I can fail the overall request and let the user know which URL(with response codes) failed. As (1) is triggered by one synchronous POST request. It's effectively an orchestration layer.

(3) Set a time out on each of the concurrent requests made in (1) so the overall request time can be guaranteed up front.

I'm familar with Jersey but I'm new to reactive jersey. So I'm wondering is (1) to (3) possible with reactive jersey client and if so are the examples online of this in use?

I could write it using threads myself but I like the thought of having this handled at the framework level. And jersey rx seems a good fit for this.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic for asking for outside resources. But if you want official resources, go to the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/rx-client.html). If you scroll to the bottom there are links to example projects, which is a supplement to the documentation

Comment: Hi Peeskillet I've read the official documentation and checked the official examples on github( in particular the examples with Jersey rx and weather forecasts for destinations...will post the link later) but it didn't answer the above questions for me unfortunately. So I'd like to keep this question open if possible  ...updated with link to relevant example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/rx-client-webapp/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/rx/agent/ObservableAgentResource.java

Comment: Use the documentation and examples to practice using the APIs and find out their capabilites, and you will find your use case can be implemented.

Comment: Hi Peeskillet I'm trying to use the jersey rx client API for my use case but I've been struggling reading the docs and playing with the examples. Hence why Im posting here

Comment: But you haven't posted a real _on-topic_ question. You are asking for tutorials, which is off-topic. What you should be posting is what you have tried, and where you are stuck. What isn't working.

Comment: if you don't want to answer the question that's fine. I have asked three specific questions and if you don't want to answer them that's fine and the same if you wish to vote to close it. I have tried the docs and the examples so these are the questions I have as I didn't find the answers I need.

Comment: And FYI it is on topic. The topic is how to use Jersey Rx to post a dynamic number of POST requests and gather the results of all the posts and ensure we have a default timeout using Jersey Rx.